# Como configurar un Certificado SSL gratuito de Let's Encrypt en Apache

Tags: apache, apache2, ssl, letsencrypt, certificado-ssl

Estaba buscando al respecto de los Certificados SSL de Let's Encrypt, así también sobre la configuración en Apache.

Encontré información al respecto, en el [Sitio Oficial de Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/) .

Realicé los distintos pasos que encontré en variados sitios, la creación de los elementos de verificación y realicé hasta la generación de los archivos de certificado, pero entonces me surgió la duda:

**¿Como se configura un Certificado SSL de Let's Encrypt en Apache?**

Comment: Hay un cliente para let's encrypt que puede hacer el proceso mucho mas sencillo y rapido. [CERT BOT - https://certbot.eff.org](https://certbot.eff.org) Sin embargo hacer el proceso descrito arriba, ayuda a entender como funciona el cliente de cert bot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Les comparto mi solución, para la configuración de los certificados.

#### Primero, lo primero.

Para realizar la generación de los certificados, lo primero que necesitaremos sera una maquina con **GNU/Linux**, no importa la distribución, lo único que se necesita es que tenga un pinguino en su interior :)

En mi caso, usaré una maquina virtual, **¿Porque?** Bueno, de acuerdo a varios sitios de internet, el generador de certificados usado por Let's Encrypt, instala demasiadas dependencias en nuestro ordenador, de modo que, por **seguridad**, no creo conveniente usarla en un equipo de **producción**.

La maquina a usar sera:

> Debian 7 x64 (No importa la arquitectura)

---

### Empecemos

En nuestra maquina, vamos a empezar clonando el repositorio de *Let's Encrypt*, esto lo realizamos de la siguiente manera:

> git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt

Después de ejecutar este comando, ingresamos al directorio:

> cd letsencrypt/

---

### Continuemos...

Ya tenemos el 50% del proceso realizado, lo que hemos clonado corresponde al script que se encarga de la generación y comprobación de los certificados.

**Así que...**

Estando en el directorio de *Let's Encrypt*, vamos a proceder con la generación del certificado, **cabe aclarar que un solo Certificado SSL puede servir para un dominio como para todos sus subdominios.**

**¿Como generamos el certificado?**

Si lo queremos para **un solo dominio**, solo bastaría con ejecutar la siguiente instrucción:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a manual -d dominio.com
```

Pero, si necesitamos para **varios subdominios**, solo basta con agregar el parámetro `-d` cuantas veces sea necesario:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a manual -d dominio.com -d www.dominio.com -d mail.dominio.com
```

**Nota:** *Sobra indicar que reemplazamos "dominio.com" por nuestro dominio y subdominios.*

**En este momento, si es la primera vez que generamos un certificado, es normal que se empiecen a instalar dependencias que serán usadas por Let's Encrypt**

---

### Verificación de dominio

A continuación procedemos con la verificación de nuestro dominio (y subdominios si este es el caso), para lo cual tendremos que olvidarnos de contactar a alguien para revise la bandeja de entrada, ya que Let's Encrypt se basa en un protocolo, inventado por ellos, conocido como ACME Protocol (Protocolo ACME).

Un ejemplo del protocolo ACME, lo podríamos apreciar a continuación:

[image: ACME]

En pocas, palabras:

> Pones un texto X en un lugar Y, a continuación Let's Encrypt verificara ese lugar Y y comparara si el texto X es el correcto.

Así se verifica la propiedad de un dominio.

**Por lo tanto...**

Antes de realizar la verificación del dominio, se realizaran algunas verificaciones de nuestra parte, son 4 preguntas a las que, podríamos responder afirmativamente, sin necesidad de leerlas:

#### En la primera pregunta, se nos pide nuestra dirección de correo electrónico.

[image: Confirmación de Correo Electrónico]

#### ¿Acepta usted los términos y condiciones?

[image: Acepta Términos y Condiciones]

#### ¿Desea compartir su dirección de correo electrónico con la Electronic Frontier Foundation?

[image: Compartir Email]

#### Y por ultimo, ¿Acepta el hecho de que su IP sera registrada, como la solicitante del certificado?

[image: Registrar IP]

#### Y al final...

[image: ACME]

Vemos un par de lineas, para entenderlas mejor, debemos recordar el ejemplo de la X y Y, previamente indicados:

```
X -> Linea Roja (El texto)
Y -> Linea Azul (Ubicación del texto)
```

Es decir, que en nuestro caso, *Let's Encrypt*, **buscara** en dicho directorio, el texto ***ujnNRM2mmW3B...***

Para ello lo único que necesitamos es crear dicha ruta en nuestro servidor web.

***Ejemplo (Apache):***

```
cd /var/www/
mkdir -p .well-known/acme-challenge/
touch ujnNRM2mmW3Bz...
```

Y dentro de dicho archivo ***"ujnNRM2mmW3Bz..."***, ingresar el texto de la linea Roja.

Al final, presionamos **Enter**, en nuestra maquina de *Let's Encrypt.*

Nuestro certificados se encontraran en el directorio:

> /etc/letsencrypt/live/**dominio.com**

---

### Configuración en Apache

Lo primero que debemos hacer, es el traslado de nuestro archivos a nuestro servidor, donde serán instalados, en mi caso los he copiado en el directorio:

> /etc/ssl/dominio.com

Allí encontraremos los siguientes archivos:

> cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem

En el caso de Apache, no se usa `fullchain.pem`.

No resta sino, dirigirnos a la configuración de nuestro sitio, en este caso, debemos dirigirnos al directorio:

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/dominio.com

Y allí escribir la configuración, para SSL:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName dominio.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/dominio.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/dominio.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/dominio.com/chain.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

Guardamos, y reiniciamos Apache.

---

### Voila

[image: SSL OK]

Comment: En Windows no se puede?, si estoy usando WAMP por ejemplo.